# Launch Raspberry Pi Task Manager GUI from terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi, taskmanager

I am doing some remote work on a Raspberry Pi over SSH with X11 enabled. What is the command to launch the Task Manager GUI from the terminal?

Comment: Which Window Manager are you using? Do you know it's command line name?

Comment: I believe the default Raspbian GUI. I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's command is `lxtask`:

```sh
user@raspbian:~$ lxtask
```

If you want to send the window to the PC where you opened the SSH from, you need to add `-X` to your SSH connection command.